# Angular Material md-select item is not saved at window reload

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angular-material, getter-setter

I have a drop down list from where the users are supposed to select the progress for a task. The progress has to be populated at all times, so it cannot be blank. The problem is that I cannot get the controller to get and set the progress information from the service. I admit that I have trouble understanding the logic behind populating the md-select drop down list with the initial progress and getting/setting the new status. I looked at md-select directive on the Angular Material site, but they give clear guidelines about md-on-open and md-on-close, not about initial/default value.
So here is my md-select code in my template:

```
<md-toolbar style="background-color: #e6e3f4">
  <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        <span flex></span>
        <md-input-container style="margin: 1px;" ng-controller="SelectOptGroupController"> 
            <md-select ng-model="progress">
              <md-option ng-repeat="progress in progresses" value="{{progress}}">{{progress}}</md-option>
            </md-select>
        </md-input-container>
  </div>
  </md-toolbar>
```

It is included in a toolbar, I don't know if that makes any difference or not.

The controller looks like this:

```
angular
.module('myApp')
.controller('SelectOptGroupController', ['$scope', '$mdDialog', '$stateParams', 'ScorecardStatus', function($scope, $mdDialog, $stateParams, ScorecardStatus) {
$scope.employee.id = $stateParams.employeeid;
$scope.employee.startDate = $stateParams.startdate;
$scope.employee.endDate = $stateParams.enddate;

    $scope.progresses = [
      "Not started",
      "In progress",
      "Quality analysis finished",
      "Sent for review",
      "Completed"
  ];


  $scope.getSelectedProgress = function(progress){
        getProgress().then(function(progress){
            $scope.progress = progress;
        })
    }
    //console.log($scope.progress);
```

}])

And here's the service making the calls to and from the Database:

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .factory('ScorecardStatus', function($http,$rootScope,$q){
        var progress;

        function setProgress() {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'php/setScorecardProgress.php',
                    data: {status: selectedStatus, id: employee.id, startdate: employee.startDate, enddate: employee.endDate}
            });
        }

        function getProgress() {
            if (!progress)
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: 'php/getScorecardProgress.php'
            });

            return progress;
        }

        return {
            getProgress: getProgress
        }

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: any update on my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define `id` for each `progress` you are using in `md-select`. As I shown in my example, because you have unique `id` releated to each `progress` you can identify any progress by its `id`. so define your `progress` model with the `id` you want to select when the page loads.

```
<md-toolbar>
  <div layout="row" layout-aling="end center">
    <span flex></span>
    <md-input-container>
      <md-select ng-model="progress">
        <md-option ng-repeat="progress in progresses" value="{{progress.id}}">{{progress.name}}</md-option>
      </md-select>
    </md-input-container>
  </div>
</md-toolbar>
```

JS

```
.controller('TempController', function($scope) {
$scope.progress = 2;
$scope.progresses = [
  {
    name: "Not started",
    id: 0
  },
  {
    name: "In progress",
    id: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Quality analysis finished",
    id: 2
  },
  {
    name: "Sent for review",
    id: 3
  },
  {
    name: "Completed",
    id: 4
  }
];
});
```

Here is the wokring example. http://codepen.io/next1/pen/zBNRMe

Comment: The issue was a bit more simple than what you proposed, in the way that I needed to use ng-value instead of value in the md-option. I didn't know the subtleties of data binding with AngularJS, and also the demo example on the Angular Material site is with value, not ng-value.

Comment: Great.  So you found the answer on your own.  Please try to comment if you find the answer is not what you looking for, so that people can try to make it simpler or clear any doubts. :)